# c++ fatal error c1001:an internal error has occurred in the compiler

Tags: c++-cli

I have to mix C++ with dot net C++. I see this error. I have already Googled a lot. Tried many methods. Still not working. Any help appreciated.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {

        typedef struct
        {
            char all_srting[200];
            char name_1[100];
            char Max_1[100];
            char Min_1[100];
        }power_line_name;

        int numLines;
        StreamReader ^ sr1=File::OpenText("powerline.txt");
        while(sr1->ReadLine())
        {
            numLines++;
        }
        power_line_name* power_list=new power_line_name[numLines];

        StreamReader ^ sr=File::OpenText("powerline.txt");
        array<System::String ^> ^power_line;
        array<System::String ^> ^power_line_nospace;
        array<System::String ^> ^d_line;
        array<System::String ^> ^all_powrline_string;
        int i=0;
        char nstring[100];

        try
        {
            String^ s="";
            while (s=sr->ReadLine())
            {
                power_line=s->Split(':');
                power_line_nospace=power_line[1]->Split(' ');       
                d_line=power_line_nospace[1]->Split('|');
                for(int a=0;a<d_line->Length;a++)
                {
                    pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wch = PtrToStringChars(d_line[a]);
                    size_t origsize = wcslen(wch) + 1;
                    size_t convertedChars = 0;
                    if(a==0)
                    {
                        wcstombs_s(&convertedChars, power_list[i].name_1, origsize, wch, _TRUNCATE);
                        //strcat_s(power_list[i].name_1, " (char *)");
                    }
                    if(a==1)
                    {
                        wcstombs_s(&convertedChars, power_list[i].Max_1, origsize, wch, _TRUNCATE);
                        //strcat_s(power_list[i].Max_1, " (char *)");
                    }
                    if(a==2)
                    {
                        wcstombs_s(&convertedChars, power_list[i].Min_1, origsize, wch, _TRUNCATE);
                        //strcat_s(power_list[i].Min_1, " (char *)");
                    }

                }
                i++;

            }



            Console::WriteLine(s);
        }
        finally
        {
            if(sr)
                delete (IDisposable^)(sr);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

I get this message: power_line=s->Split(':');<-----fatal error c1001:an internal error has occurred in the compiler

and

error fatal error lnk1000 internal error during image::bulidimage

what can i do?

Comment: What is your compiler and version? Did you search its bug tracker?

Comment: i use visual studio 2008 91605-270-4713616-60082

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error when use boost::iequals to compare two std::string like below:

```
std::for_each(bds.begin(),bds.end(),[&](std::string str){if(boost::iequals("must",str)) printf("matched\n");});
```

i compiled this code with vs 2010 and boost version 1.58.

To solved the error just replace the std::for_each() with for().so i guess the compile r and boosts lib conflicted.